# CWBUNDBS, DB2 client doesn't work suddenly

Tags: database, db2, db2-400

CWBUNDBS was working perfectly but it's not working now (not running, not open), why?

I unistall and reinstall the application a couple of times but it's still not working.

Comment: You may want to explain what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions to this problem is:

**Windows XP**

Go to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\IBM\Client Access\Config

In this directory exist a file with name Unity.Toolkit.User$YOURUSERNAME.ser

This file is corrupt, delete it and try to open the application. A new file will be generated.

**Windows 7**

Go to C:\Users\Public\Documents\IBM\Client Access\Config

In this directory exist a file with name Unity.Toolkit.User$YOURUSERNAME.ser

This file is corrupt, delete it and try to open the application. A new file will be generated.

Comment: How did you figure out that this was the issue? Do you have error codes? Not Working, Not Running, Not Open, are pretty generic symptoms, and you have given us nothing to help us understand if your situation is similar to ours or not. What is this Unity file? What settings will we loose if we delete it?